# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 - viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode4.3

I'm getting this error and curious whats triggering it. From what I've read it's usually about animating inside viewDidLoad or blocking a UIAlertView.

1.If I comment out the scrollView block of code, the error goes away.

2.If I leave the scrollView code and comment out from 360Controller start to page One end. The warning goes away.

3.Is it because of memory overload?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.view.hidden = YES;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

//SCROLLVIEW Start
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024*6, 768)];
scrollView.bounces = NO;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
//SCROLLVIEW End


//Poster Vertical Scroller STart
posterVerticalScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1024*3, 0, 1024, 768)];
[posterVerticalScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 768*3)];
posterVerticalScroller.bounces = NO;
posterVerticalScroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
[scrollView addSubview:posterVerticalScroller];
//Poster Vertical Scroller End


//Overview Start
overView = [[OverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
overView.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView addSubview:overView.view];
//OverView End

//Landing start
landingView = [[LandingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
landingView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView addSubview:landingView.view];
//Landing End


//360Controller Start
rotateController * rotateAnim = [[rotateController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
rotateAnim.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*2, 0, 1024, 768);
[scrollView addSubview:rotateAnim.view];

animateHouse = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100 + 1024*2, 200, 800, 450)];
  // animateHouse.animationImages = rotateImg;
  //animateHouse.animationDuration = 3.0;
  // animateHouse.animationRepeatCount = 1;
  // [animateHouse startAnimating];
animateHouse.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
animateHouse.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
[self.view addSubview:animateHouse];
//360Controller End

//Poster 1 start
poster1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"poster01.png"]];
poster1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1250, 768);
[posterVerticalScroller addSubview:poster1];
poster1Items = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"poster01_items.png"]];
poster1Items.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
[posterVerticalScroller addSubview:poster1Items];    
//Poster 1 end


//Poster 2 Start
poster2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"poster02.png"]];
poster2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 768, 1162, 768);
[posterVerticalScroller addSubview:poster2];
poster2Items = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"poster02_items.png"]];
poster2Items.frame = CGRectMake(0, 768, 1024, 768);
[posterVerticalScroller addSubview:poster2Items];
//Poster 2 End



//Poster 3 Start
poster3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"poster03.png"]];
poster3.frame = CGRectMake(0, 768*2, 1536, 768);
[posterVerticalScroller addSubview:poster3];
poster3Items = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"poster03_items.png"]];
poster3Items.frame = CGRectMake(0, 768*2, 1024,768 );
[posterVerticalScroller addSubview:poster3Items]; 
//Poster 3 End



//PageOne Start
UIImageView * pageOneBg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1024*4, 0, 1024, 768)];
pageOneBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page360_landing_full.png"];
[scrollView addSubview:pageOneBg];


UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(1024*4+750, 520, 200, 200);
[button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(loadingTEst) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[scrollView addSubview:button];
//PageOne End

//Page 2
UIImageView *pageTwoBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1024*5, 0, 1024, 768)];
pageTwoBG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Page06_Full.png"];
[scrollView addSubview:pageTwoBG];    

UIButton *buttonTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
buttonTwo.frame = CGRectMake(1024*5+0, 550, 250, 100);
[buttonTwo setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[scrollView addSubview:buttonTwo];
//Page 2 END

}
```

Comment: What happens if you comment everything _but_ the scrollview?

Comment: If I comment out everything in viewDidLoad except scrollView. The warning goes away.

Comment: It might not directly be going wrong in viewDidLoad, I see that you are instantiating additional view controllers here, are any of them being presented modally?

Comment: at the end of the posted code, button and buttonTwo when tapped, calls loadingTEst and loadMap which presents modal viewControllers.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your animation code in viewDidAppear.  If the animations only need to run when the view is loaded, then use a boolean to check if the view has been reloaded.